# How to explicitly close database connection in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, connection-pooling

In my project we are using JPA for querying from database. We are facing problem while running the performance and it throws exception connection unavailable.

I did check for other sources online. It is mentioned to add following properties - maxIdle, minIdle, and minEvictableIdleTimeMillis to the data source. I have set above properties along with initial-size, max-active, remove-abandoned, remove-abandoned-timeout, min-evictable-idle-time-millis etc. But it is not working.

Few resources suggest to close connection explicitly. But I am not sure how can I explicitly get the current DB connection in JPA and close it. I have included the code which I am referring.

Any suggestion on this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
Repository class:

public interface checkRepository extends JpaRepository<CheckEntity, Long> {
    CheckEntity findById(String id);
}

Service class:
class Service{

    public void method(){
        try{
            checkRepo.findById(id);
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }finally{
            //Close the connection here 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615246