# Spring JPA with Hibernate transactions deadlock

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, mariadb

I have a Spring (core) 5.3.18 application configured with a mixed XML/annotation-driven approach.
To access the backing MariaDB, I use Hibernate core 5.6.7.Final and JPA (`javax.persistence-api:2.2`) with an HikariCP 4.0.3 connection pool.
The data source is an `HikariDataSource` with a default connection pool size of 10, and with the `leakDetectionThreshold` set to 6 seconds (transactions are really short).
The configured `JpaTransactionManager` fom spring uses as `entityManagerFactory` a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` that configures Hibernate via the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`.

At runtime, with just one thread performing DB operations everything works fine.
When multiple threads start requiring the DB at the same time though, threads get stuck on what seems like a starvation condition, all waiting to retrieve a connection.
HikariCP reports the following leak, reported 10 times for all of the connections available in the pool:

```
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ...
```

In my tests, for `N` threads running apparently I needed a connection pool size of exactly `N*2` to avoid this behaviour, which led me to think that by some mistake (or expected behaviour unknown to me) the application I set up consumes two connections for every transaction, instead of just one.
This would explain why not even one request succeeds when all threads are sent requests at the same time, but it's just my guess: each of them acquires the first connection object at some point, and then when they try to acquire the second they all get stuck at the same time.

I really can't figure out what's happening behind Spring's and JPA's magic though. In my understanding of the documentation, a public method of a `@Transactional` class be wrapped in a spring proxy that gets the connection just before the transaction occurs, and closes it (actually causing the connection to return to the pool instead of bein phisically closed, see also [When are connections returned to the connection pool with Spring JPA (Hibernate) Entity Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486104/when-are-connections-returned-to-the-connection-pool-with-spring-jpa-hibernate)) after the transactin is committed/rolled-back.

Something's amiss, though. I would really appreciate any help or hint about what to do, I've been stuck on this for ages.

Below is the XML spring configuration. There are no additional `persistence.xml` nor `hibernate.properties/cfg.xml`.

```xml
<bean id="dataSourceHikari" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="validationTimeout" value="3000" />
    <property name="readOnly" value="false" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="60000" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${db.maxPoolSize:10}" />
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="6000" />
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceHikari" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="my.application.package" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

My DB layer instead looks like this below.
Each application thread simply invokes `DBLayerClass#createSession(String)` on the `@Autowired DBLayerClass myDBObj` once for every incoming request.

```java
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
/* other stuff */

@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class, MyCustomExceptions.class})
public class DBLayerClass {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public Session createSession(String sessionId) throws MyCustomExceptions {
        try {
            if (getSessionById(sessionId) != null)
                throw new MyCustomExceptions("...");
            Session session = new Session(sessionId);
            entityManager.persist(session);
            return session;
        } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
            throw new MyCustomExceptions("...", e);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new MyCustomExceptions("...", e);
        }
    }

    private Session getSessionById(String sessionId) throws MyCustomExceptions {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

            CriteriaQuery<Session> cq = cb.createQuery(Session.class);
            Root<Session> from = cq.from(Session.class);

            cq.where(cb.equal(from.get("sessionId"), sessionId));

            TypedQuery<Session> q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);

            return q.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw new MyCustomExceptions("...", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The fields on my `@Entity` classes use `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` annotations for `Long` primary keys, and other regular annotations such as `@Column` or `@Temporal`. Most fancy ones are collections with `@OneToMany`.

I re-wrote a simpler and basic test scenario, made to start a bunch of worker threads which keep sending db requests in a loop. A handful of `createSession(...)` might work at first, but the test starves soon enough and the above leaks are reported by HikariCP.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/dao-test.xml" })
public class MyTestClass {

    @Autowired
    private DBLayerClass db;

    @Test
    public void testConcurrentUsage() throws Exception {
        Callable<Exception> c = new Callable<Exception>() {
            private AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong(0);

            @Override
            public Exception call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    long id;
                    while ((id = nextId.incrementAndGet()) < 100L) {
                        db.createSession(String.format("session-%d", id));
                    }
                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return e;
                }
            }
        };

        final int nThreads = 30;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[nThreads];
        ArrayList<Future<Exception>> threadResults =  new ArrayList<>(nThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            FutureTask<Exception> threadResult = new FutureTask<>(c);
            threadResults.add(threadResult);
            threads[i] = new Thread(threadResult);
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (Future<Exception> result : threadResults) {
            Exception e = result.get();
            if (e != null) {
                for (Thread thread : threads) {
                    thread.stop();
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, these below are the dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.23.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
  <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SOrry but there is too little information. You speak of a test, which isn't included. If there is a leak something must be getting the connection and that must be your own code. You are using HikariCP so please remove the validation query and rely on the connection validation of JDBC4 (unless you are using a very very very old driver you need a validation query).

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the validation query which I previously added and forgot in one of the desperate tries to understand the issue. I also rewrote a minimal unit test which also replicates connection leaks in the same way as in my original application (which is a bit less minimal to report here). Please let me know should you think I need to provide yet more information. Thanks, in the meantime.

Comment: I would suggest using a thread pool rather than manually handling threads, but alas. Do you have a hidden `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.properties/cfg.xml` somewhere in your classpath as well? Could you specify the versions of Spring, Hikari and Hibernate you are using? Finally what is with the additional proxyfactorybean? What happens if you leave that out?

Comment: I did some testing and when using the MySQL dialects with the MariaDB i quite constantly get timeouts. When using a proper MariaDB103Dialect dialect for hibernate things do succeed. So it seems to be due to the wrong dialect that things go wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum unfortunately we're stuck for now on MariaDB 5.5, so I tried with `MariaDB53Dialect` which would seem to be valid for 5.3 and later 5.x releases, but I still get the same behaviour. Your findings about timeouts though seem to point in the direction of some driver misconfiguration. I wasn't able to understand what, though. In the meantime I also updated the question by including the dependencies. To answer your other question no, there's no `persistence.xml` nor `cfg.xml`.

Comment: I suspect that something in the dialect (not the driver) is causing a deadlock on the database. Which is fixed in later dialects or MariaDB implementations. Could be a thing like not using a sequence for the primary key for instance.

Comment: Using an id with auto generated keys (IDENTITY insteadof AUTO) makes it also work. So it appears to be an issue with using a SEQUENCE or TABLE as a primary key that makes it fail in this combination, probably due to some deadlock in the database itself. You might need to tweak some settings there or switch to an auto-increment column for the id.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was it, thank you so much! I had `SEQUENCE` generated fields for PKs. I tried updating the schema to use mariadb's `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead and updated the `@Entity` classes to use the `IDENTITY` strategy, and it worked. I updated the question title, tags, and infos to be more fitting and to provide also context about my entities. I'll gladly accept this as an answer, should you re-write your comment as such.